# редактирование eps файла

Tags: изображения, latex

У меня есть картинки в формате eps, каждая из которых состоит из 20-30 подкартинок (поэтому вручную менять с помощью Paint как-то не вариант) одинакового размера. На каждой подкартинке есть надпись MeV на английском. Мне нужно поменять её на русский (MeV->МэВ). Что я пробовал:

1. Я работаю на Linux Fedora, поэтому просто открываю файл eps текстовым редактором и пытаюсь изменить MeV->МэВ. Текстовый редактор Emacs при сохранении требует выбрать кодировку, т. к. он стандартно русский язык не поддерживает. Я пробовал любые кодировки, но т. к. русский язык у меня на Linux не установлен, это не помогает, в итоге вместо "МэВ" пишет кракозябры.
   Я пробовал перенести файл на ПК с Windows и отредактировать там и открыть eps файл в online eps viewer в браузере. Аналогично, пишет кракозябры вместо "МэВ".
2. Мне коллега сказал (рисунки мы вставляет в документы в Latex), что есть утилита \psfrag, которая позволяет через Latex менять надписи в .eps файле. Я пробовал её применить, но у меня там каких-то зависимостей не хватает. Поскольку я в Latex слабо ориентируюсь, мне в этом сложно разобраться.

Вопрос: может есть какие-то более простые пути? Ведь .eps документ - это текстовый файл и по большому счёту мне в текстовом файле нужно изменить MeV->МэВ, но там что-то с кодировками не так?

Comment: [Написано](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-edit-EPS-files-online), что [vectr.com](https://vectr.com/) может помочь

Comment: vectr.com не открывает .eps файл. После загрузки просто пустое окно.

Comment: Немного костыльно, однако [SVG Converter](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-converter) конвертирует `eps` в `svg` и наоборот. Воспользуйтесь им перед vectr

Comment: Так тоже не работает. Просто пустой экран.

Comment: Все зависит от того как и в какой программе сделан Ваш eps. Если он сделан в программах. типа LibreOffice Draw, то про редактирование текста можете забыть. Напрямую (и с помощью psfrag) текст в eps можно редактировать, только если он состоит из простых символов ASCII (латиница и буквы), без какого-либо форматирования. Можно попробовать использовать две программы: adobe illustrator: для нее eps - это родной формат (.ai-это немного измененный eps) или Inkscape. И скорее всего, перед работой с содержимым файла надо будет всё разгруппировать. Но это может не сработать, если файл сделан некорректно

Comment: У меня с svg не работает. Выдаёт ошибку error_offline_full. Принтскрин сделал.

Comment: Я сейчас пробовал Inkscape использовать. Он как бы может заменить MeV->МэВ, но все пробелы убирает, так что получается грязь.